# What is the `cv` command to set default language?

Tags: cv, default-settings

Looking in the API V3, I can find the default language in Setting but not how to set it to `fr_FR`.

I've tried commands like `cv api Setting.create lcMessages="FR"` but they return nothing or errors.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
cv api Setting.create lcMessages="fr_FR"
```

Make sure you use the correct language code.

Note: Sometimes you need to clear CiviCRM cache to apply changes.

Comment: with the french translations files uploaded it's even better! ;-) thanks Pradeep

Comment: did that work ?

Comment: yes, thanks I had used previously fr_FR and flushed caches but I only forgot to upload localization files... that's why I was wondering how it was supposed to work. :-)